# sum of 2D array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a situation where I need to generate total sales of each month.

I can show total sales of 12 month in a certain area but I need to show total sales of any month of a certain area. i.e: total sales of June at Head Office area.
my sample code is as follows:

```
while($area = mysql_fetch_array($exe_area))
{
    for ($m=1; $m<=12; $m++) {
        ......... 
        echo $total_sold;

        $sales_of_year+= $total_sold;

    } // end of month listing....

    echo $sales_of_year;

} // end of area listing...
```

Answer (score 0):

U may try this !!!

```
  $tmp  = explode( '|', $str );
  $data = array();

  foreach ( $tmp as $k => $v )
   {
     $data[] = explode( ',', $v );
    }
```

Comment: don't understand.. please do give me a easy example with the variable given in my code

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your data is being retrieved from the database, in which case you can extract the total sum with your query:

```
SELECT SUM(column_name) FROM table_name;
```

Or, to analyse a particular month, depending on your database schema, you can do:

```
SELECT SUM(column_name) FROM table_name WHERE month = 'June';
```

Comment: actually the months are generated during output not from the database table. i think we need to push the $total_sold to any 2D array. i.e: array[head_office][june] = 5000, array[branch_office][june] = 7000 and then sum of total June's amount.

Comment: In which case, you need to give more information about the data, I have no idea what data is stored in `$area`, for example, which makes it difficult to give an exact solution